# When using keyword 'new' to create an object from prototype, can you still access in the parent object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm using code like the following

```
function parent(a){
    this.a=a
}

parent.prototype.child=function(){
    this.parent=...?
}

p=new parent("bla")
```

I'd like to be able to create a child object from the parent like so...

```
c=new p.child()
```

and be able to access the 'parent' object while creating the child object, so that it has reference to it. Like you would normally with the keyword 'this' from within the prototype function. Obviously in this case 'this' refers to the new object being created.

Is it possible to do this without passing the 'parent' object in through the parameters?

Thanks